is there a google classroom api answer to multiple choice submission function?
I want to submit google classroom answer to multiple choice question submission. but I could not get any function to do that. however I can do assignment submission using modifyAttachments function.
I am developing flutter with dart app.
I want to submit multipleChoiceSubmission and shortAnswerSubmission questions but i cannot submit them since i see no function do that.
